# How to validate input field phone with accurate Australian format using jQuery Validation?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to make an input (phone) field not required but validated according to Australian phone number.

```
        <div>
            <label for="contactPhone">Your Phone: </label>
            <input type="phone" class="form-control eform__phone"
                   id="contactPhone" name="phone"
                   placeholder="e.g. 04000000000">
        </div>
```

**The JavaScript:**

```
  /**
   * validate phone number according to australian format
   * Ref: https://ilikekillnerds.com/2014/08/regular-expression-for-validating-australian-phone-numbers-including-landline-and-mobile/
   */
  jQuery.validator.addMethod("phoneAU", function(value, element) {
    var phoneExpression = /^\({0,1}((0|\+61)(2|4|3|7|8)){0,1}\){0,1}(\ |-){0,1}[0-9]{2}(\ |-){0,1}[0-9]{2}(\ |-){0,1}[0-9]{1}(\ |-){0,1}[0-9]{3}$/;

    if (value.match(phoneExpression)) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }, jQuery.validator.messages.phoneAU || "Please specify a valid phone number");
```

And then used the following in the validate rules function

```
   phone: {
     phoneAU: true
   },
```

I am using jQuery validation. However, it is considering as required. I do not want it to be required. I just want to make sure that whenever user fills it up, then they fill it up with the proper Australian format of phone number.

Comment: `if (value.length === 0 || value.match(phoneExpression)) { return true }`?

Comment: Please add as an answer. It worked. I see what you did. Thnks

Comment: You are supposed to incorporate "OR" `this.optional(element)` into your conditional in order to test if the field is "optional".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *previously* accepted answer is not the normal way to handle this situation.  In order to preserve the ability to use a custom rule, while not making it mandatory, use "OR" `this.optional(element)` as part of the conditional, which is how the default rules in the plugin are constructed.

```
if (this.optional(element) || value.match(phoneExpression)) {
  return true;
}
return false;
```

or simply this single line shorthand version...

```
return this.optional(element) || value.match(phoneExpression);
```

Comment: You're right, this looks like the more appropriate way to handle this indeed. Upvoted.

Comment: Thnks. I didnot know of this way

Answer (score 1):

Just change your "validated" condition to this:

```
if (value.length === 0 || value.match(phoneExpression)) {
  return true;
}
```

**Edit**: see @Sparky's answer for a more optimal/appropriate solution.

Comment: This is not the correct way.  Inspecting the default rules, which operate the way the OP desires, will show that there is a bit of code to ensure the field remains "optional".

Comment: @Sparty Not sure to follow, but I'm no jquery-validate expert so I might be missing something. What do you mean by "Inspecting the default rules"?

Comment: I simply mean look at the source code of the plugin to see how its rules are constructed.  The conditionals all use "OR" `this.optional(element)` to test if the field is "optional".  I'm posting an answer now.